# How would you style this html so that everything falls into a table?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-tables

How would you make the following html fall into a table-like structure where each `div.comment_column` falls horizontally next to one another? I prefer to use CSS and not tables:

```
<div class="comments_div">

    <div class="comment_column">
        <div id="comment_title_23" class="comment_title">
            What do you think of the lyrics?
            <a href="/comment_titles/23" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a>
        </div>
        <div class="comment" id="comment_4">
             Great lyrics!
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="comment_column">
        <div id="comment_title_25" class="comment_title">
            What should my next song be?
            <a href="/comment_titles/25" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a>
        </div>
        <div class="comment" id="comment_4">
             Nice job! Do a another song next.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="comment_column">
        <div id="comment_title_26" class="comment_title">
            Feedback
            <a href="/comment_titles/26" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a>
        </div>
        <div class="comment" id="comment_4">
             Awesome stuff... next time rap a little more than sing but still great job.
        </div>   
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you want it to look like a table, that's usually a sign that your content is the type of content that belogns in a table.

Comment: moe provided a nice solution that bypasses table. Why use tables then?

Comment: Tables can be much more accessible if the data within it meant to be in a table. Tables are still quite useful for tabular data. We just don't use them for page layout anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these to your css :

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

.comment_colum {
    float: left;
    /* width: 200px; <-- can set a width here */
}
```

And change :

```
<div class="comments_div">
```

to :

```
<div class="comments_div clearfix">
```

Comment: Awesome! The only thing is that `comment` stays on the same line of `comment_title`. I want it to go on the next line below it. How would I make that happen?

Comment: I need to see your css but try adding this to css `.comment_column .comment {clear:both;}`

Comment: Actually one more thing... the entire "table", if it has a short enough width, seems to stay on the same line as the element above it (a comment form). I have `display:block; clear:both;` on both the form and the table. What else should I do?

Comment: `.comments_div {width:100%;}` ? and make sure you arent floating the 'form'